# Stable version of Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql5.5

I am plan to do some real application, here i finalized to use mysql as a backend. And my question is Currently which MySQL version is stable. Also want the major pitfalls for MySQL 5.5 if MySQL 5.6 is stable. Please share your views here. Any commands would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely all of this should have gone into the mix to help you decide on MySQL.

Comment: I don't really understand why you would ask "Currently which MySQL version is stable" and wait for an answer rather than just looking on the MySQL website and getting the answer straight away.

Answer (score 2):

Use whatever version is in your distro's package repo. Seriously. Unless you have very specific needs that require you to run the absolute newest stable, just use your distribution's packaged MySQL.

Comment: What if he's running an unstable distro?

Comment: Well then by definition, no MySQL he runs on it will ever be stable.

Comment: What if he's running a stable distro but they push out a bug fix for MySQL.  Doesn't the fact that MySQL changed contradict the idea that it is stable?

Comment: No, not at all. "stable" doesn't mean "immutable". Rather, it means that it had passed the most rigorous battery of tests they can throw at it, **and** that it has been run by users in the "unstable" branch for some time without any issues.